# Count Color and Grey image on a folder, Matlab

Tags: matlab

How do I count what image is color and what image is grey on a folder.

```
    filenames = dir('...\data\*.jpg');
    img = cell(1,length(filenames));
    for j = 1:length(filenames)
    nume = filenames(j).name;
    img{j} = imread(['...\data\' filenames(j).name ]);  
    if size(img{j}, 3) == 3
        disp('Color');
    else
        disp('Grey');
    end
    end
```

My approach did not work.

Comment: Why isn't that good enough? Can you explain what you got and what you expected to get?

Comment: These are the images http://prntscr.com/i6tnri . And that show up http://prntscr.com/i6to4v . Are incorrect.

Comment: You may want to print the filenames alongside the classification because since you're not sorting the filenames, the ordering may not be what you expect. Also a greyscale image can still have 3 color channels, they would just all be the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will change nothing from what you are actually doing, but in the check I would use the [ndims function](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ndims.html) instead, which returns the number of dimensions in the image matrix:

```
if (ndims(img) > 2)
    disp('RGB');
else
    disp('Grayscale');
end
```

Alternatively, you could rely on a more solid (but also more expensive) check based on [imfinfo](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imfinfo.html). The function returns a structure whose fields contain information about the specified file. One of those fields (`ColorType`) can help you discerning between RGB and graycale images:

> **ColorType**
>
> ColorType includes, but is not limited to, 'truecolor' for
>   a truecolor (RGB) image, 'grayscale' for a grayscale intensity image,
>   or 'indexed' for an indexed image.

Example:

```
file = ['...\data\' filenames(j).name ];
img{j} = imread(file);
info = imfinfo(file);

if (strcmp(info.ColorType,'grayscale'))
    disp('Grayscale');
else
    disp('RGB');
end
```

Besides this minor adjustement, what @Suever said in his comment is very important. Your code is based on the assumption that the `dir` command returns the file names in the exact same order you are seeing them in your OS... which could be true, but also wrong. In order to perform a consistent check, you should include your current file name to the result. This way, you will have a direct link between an image and its corresponding type:

```
filenames = dir('...\data\*.jpg');
img = cell(1,length(filenames));

for j = 1:length(filenames)
    file_name = filenames(j).name;
    file_img = imread(['...\data\' file_name]);

    img{j} = file_img;  

    if (ndims(file_img) > 2)
        disp([file_name ' -> RGB']);
    else
        disp([file_name ' -> Grayscale']);
    end
end
```